# MKLocalSearch return 0 value

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am developing an iOS app which required to search location and put annotation into map.
I write following code for search into Swift Language. But, it always return 0 value as response.

```
var searchRequest : MKLocalSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = address
        searchRequest.region = self.mapView.region

        var search : MKLocalSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)

        var response: MKLocalSearchResponse
        var err : NSError = NSError()
        search.startWithCompletionHandler { (
            response, err) -> Void in
            var placeMarks: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

            for mp in placeMarks{
                placeMarks.addObject(mp)
            }
            self.mapView.removeAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations)
            self.mapView.showAnnotations(placeMarks, animated: true)
        }
```

I had tried with different address, city name, state name. but no help.
So, please help me. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what this code is doing:

```
var placeMarks: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

for mp in placeMarks{
    placeMarks.addObject(mp)
}
```

First, it creates and initializes an empty array called `placeMarks`.

Then, it loops through `placeMarks` (which is *empty*) and adds its own objects to itself (but that code never executes because the array is empty to begin with).

Then, this empty `placeMarks` array is passed to `showAnnotations` which does nothing (because the array is empty).

Instead, the code should loop through the `response.mapItems` array and add the `placemark` from each `MKMapItem` object in that array to the `placeMarks` array.

Additionally, code should check that `err` is `nil` before trying to process `response`.

Finally, the local variable declarations of `response` and `err` before the call to `startWithCompletionHandler` are unnecessary.  Those variables are not needed by the completion handler which *passes* those objects that the search has created internally to the block.

The modified code might look like this:

```
//var response: MKLocalSearchResponse
//var err : NSError = NSError()

search.startWithCompletionHandler { (
    response, err) -> Void in
    if (err == nil) {
        var placeMarks: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

        for res in response.mapItems {
            if let mi = res as? MKMapItem {
                placeMarks.addObject(mi.placemark)
            }
        }

        self.mapView.removeAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations)
        self.mapView.showAnnotations(placeMarks, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just comment
 var response: MKLocalSearchResponse
 var err : NSError = NSError()
and it working..